# How to extract HTML text which has no tags using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape text from a website. However, it has no HTML tags and I therefore do not know how to grab it. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <p><strong>Número de item:</strong> <label id="itemNumber2">46369</label></p>
     0 g de grasas trans. Sin colesterol. 4.73 l.
</div>
```

The text I wish to obtain is " 0 g de grasas trans. Sin colesterol. 4.73 l.". So far, I have tried the following with Beautifulsoup:

```
for especifica in subsoup.find('div',{'class':'card-body'}).find_all(text=True, recursive=False):
  esp = especifica.replace('\xa0l','')
  descripcion_especifica.append(esp.strip())
```

The output obtained for the key 'Descripcion especifica' within a dictionary is:

```
'Descripcion especifica': ['', '0 g de grasas trans. Sin colesterol. 4.73.']
```

This is as close as I have come to obtaining the actual text. However, whenever I try to get rid of the first element of the list or merge it with the second one, I get further errors.
Does anyone know how to scrape this text?

Comment: Try this `soup.p.next_sibling`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a variety of locator strategies. The text is the last part of a div tag. You can use stripped_strings on the div, or target the child p of the div and use next_sibling to move across

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.pricesmart.com/site/sv/es/pagina-producto/46369')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#collapseOne p').next_sibling.strip().replace(u'\xa0l',''))
print([i for i in soup.select_one('#collapseOne .card-body').stripped_strings][-1].replace(u'\xa0l',''))
print([i for i in soup.select_one('.card-body:has(strong:contains("Número de item:"))').stripped_strings][-1].replace(u'\xa0l',''))
print(soup.select_one('p:has(#itemNumber2)').next_sibling.strip().replace(u'\xa0l',''))
print(soup.select_one('#collapseOne .card-body').text.split('\n')[-2].strip().replace(u'\xa0l',''))
```

You could also regex from  response text as is present within a script tag, though that would not be my choice. Pick the simplest, least complicated method e.g. the first one shown above.

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.pricesmart.com/site/sv/es/pagina-producto/46369')
print(re.search(',\{\\\\"value\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', r.text).groups(0)[0].replace(u'\xa0l',''))
```

Comment: Your first locator strategy worked perfectly, thank you very much!